# Validation Rule - All 3 fields Blank or all 3 Filled in

Tags: validation

I'm trying to create a validation rule on Lead fields Year__c Make__c Model__c
The requirement is that it's acceptable for all 3 to be blank, but it's unacceptable for 1 or 2 to be filled in, it has to be blank or all 3 need values.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? (Please [edit], and check out [ask] and [help/on-topic] to learn more about our format at SFSE).

Answer (score 1):

To figure this out, we first look at the two acceptable conditions:

```
ISBLANK(Year__c) && ISBLANK(Make__c) && ISBLANK(Model__c)

NOT(ISBLANK(Year)) && NOT(ISBLANK(Make__c)) && NOT(ISBLANK(Model__c))
```

We can algebraically reduce the second formula by way of [de Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), namely that "NOT(A) AND NOT(B)" is the same as "NOT(A OR B)", which makes it:

```
NOT(ISBLANK(Year__c) || ISBLANK(Make__c) || ISBLANK(Model__c))
```

Now, we need either of these conditions, so we use OR:

```
(ISBLANK(Year__c) && ISBLANK(Make__c) && ISBLANK(Model__c)) ||
(NOT(ISBLANK(Year__c) || ISBLANK(Make__c) || ISBLANK(Model__c)))
```

However, this would stop the save when the record matches these criteria, so we have to invert the result:

```
NOT(
  (ISBLANK(Year__c) && ISBLANK(Make__c) && ISBLANK(Model__c)) ||
  (NOT(ISBLANK(Year__c) || ISBLANK(Make__c) || ISBLANK(Model__c)))
)
```

This is kind of hard to read, but we now have a de Morgan's Law situation again: "NOT(A OR B)" becomes "NOT(A) AND NOT(B)".

```
NOT(
  (ISBLANK(Year__c) && ISBLANK(Make__c) && ISBLANK(Model__c))
) &&
NOT(
  NOT(ISBLANK(Year__c) || ISBLANK(Make__c) || ISBLANK(Model__c))
)
```

The double-NOT cancels each other out, and we're left with:

```
NOT((ISBLANK(Year__c) && ISBLANK(Make__c) && ISBLANK(Model__c))) &&
(ISBLANK(Year__c) || ISBLANK(Make__c) || ISBLANK(Model__c))
```

This one is complicated enough that I had to think it out in my head, so you may want to try some experiments on paper to prove that this works.

---

Or, alternatively, you could make a slightly more functional version:

```
0 = CASE(
    IF(ISBLANK(Year__c),1,0)+
    IF(ISBLANK(Model__c),1,0)+
    IF(ISBLANK(Make__c),1,0),
    0, 1
    3, 1
    0
)
```

In this model, we add up how many blank fields we have. If we have zero or three blank fields, we return a 1, and 0 = 1, so the record saves. If we have one or two fields, we return the default value 0, and 0 = 0, so the record does not save.

Comment: Thanks for your help sfdcfox. I was able to solve this using: AND(
OR(ISBLANK(Year__c), ISBLANK(Make__c),
ISBLANK(Model__c)) ,
NOT(AND(
ISBLANK(Year__c), ISBLANK(Make__c), ISBLANK(Model__c)
)))

Comment: @eaglefly787 The culture here on the StackExchange network is to upvote (once you gain enough reputation) and accept answers on your questions if they solved your problem. In particular, accepting an answer signals to the community that your problem has been solved, and helps other people with similar problems easily identify things that are likely to work for them too.

Answer (score 0):

AND(
OR(ISBLANK(Year__c), ISBLANK(Make__c),
ISBLANK(Model__c)) ,
NOT(AND(
ISBLANK(Year__c), ISBLANK(Make__c), ISBLANK(Model__c)
)))